# Cannot resolve symbol "Android" Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar _supporttoolbar;

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]
[image: The gradle file]

I am trying to add the following command: 
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar _supporttoolbar;
, but it is reading " cannot resolve symbol Android."

NOTE: I'm a beginner at this

Comment: cause it should be "android" with a small 'a' not with capital 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar**

Classes are case sensitive

Comment: well that's embarrassing.

Comment: Anyhow, why are you manually writing this? Android Studio shows code suggestions as you type Toolbar . Just press enter whenever the suggestions come. It will prevent a lot of problems with spelling mistakes and cases.